# how i can run infinite loop in c#

Tags: c#, .net

i want to run a infinite loop in c#. the structure i have is hirachical means every index have a list of same strucutre.

the thing look like

a person have their two child maybe the two child have two the loop is infinite how i  can run them on aspx page.

any suggestion to do that

```
public struct mystruct{
public int ID;
public List<mystruct> childs
}
```

Comment: Do you mean an infinitely recursive hierarchical structure? Recursive structures and loops are not the same thing.

Comment: why is that a struct? This may be a lot of the problem...

Comment: Running infinite loops will crash your application

Comment: You have a recursive structure. What is your problem? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: you want to run an infinite loop? `while(true){}` win

Comment: @Pontus - not with `struct`, he doesn't...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A proper recursive graph is not really possible with structs; you would need to change to a `class`:

```
public class MyType{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    private readonly List<MyType> children = new List<MyType>();
    public List<MyType> Children {get{return children;}}
}
```

The problem is that otherwise virtually every time you try to mutate them to create the cycle, you get a copy, not the same instance.

Since this is a mutable entity type, it should be a class **anyway**.

Then even something as simple as:

```
var obj = new MyType();
obj.Children.Add(obj);
```

is a recursive graph.

Answer (score 1):

```
CheckMyStruct(myStruct aStruct)
{
   doSomethingWithStruct(aStruct);
   if(aStruct.childs != null)
   { 
        foreach(myStruct aChild in aStruct.Childs)
            {
               CheckMyStruct(aChild);
            }
   }

}
```

Comment: You'll need to loop the aStruct.Childs

Comment: Yeah, types don't match, `aStruct.Childs` is `List<myStruct>`, not `myStruct`

Comment: @Magnus & @Chimoo  Absolutely.  But the basic idea is there